# Дублируются запросы JOIN ON OR

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_items_sort` (
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`division_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sort` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `shop_items_sort`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `itemdiv` (`item_id`,`division_id`);

CREATE TABLE `shop_items` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`division_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`divisions` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Есть основной раздел у товара - shop_items.division_id и дополнительные shop_items.divisions в виде (;1;;2;;3;;4;;5;)

Вторая таблица - shop_items_sort (item_id, division_id, sort)

Выдача дублирует некоторые строки и выдает несколько одинаковых.

```
id  division_id divisions
193 2   ;5;
195 2   ;5;
196 2   ;5;
197 2   ;5;
210 2   ;5;
```

```
id  division_id divisions
6   1   ;4;
20  1   ;4;
34  1   ;4;
39  1   ;4;
141 2   ;4;
```

Результаты выдачи:

```
SELECT shop_items.id FROM shop_items
  LEFT JOIN shop_items_sort as sort
    ON shop_items.id = sort.item_id and (sort.division_id = shop_items.division_id or shop_items.divisions like CONCAT('%;', sort.division_id, ';%'))
 where (shop_items.division_id = '5' or shop_items.divisions like '%;5;%' ) and shop_items.archive = '0'
 order by sort.sort limit 0, 20
```

210
195
196
193
197
193
210
195
196
197

```
SELECT shop_items.id FROM shop_items
  LEFT JOIN shop_items_sort as sort
    ON shop_items.id = sort.item_id and (sort.division_id = shop_items.division_id or shop_items.divisions like CONCAT('%;', sort.division_id, ';%'))
 where (shop_items.division_id = '4' or shop_items.divisions like '%;4;%' ) and shop_items.archive = '0'
 order by sort.sort limit 0, 20
```

20
141
6
34
39
141

НЕОБХОДИМО:

Чтобы выводились товары только по параметрам:

```
SELECT shop_items.id FROM shop_items
 where (shop_items.division_id = '4' or shop_items.divisions like '%;4;%' ) and shop_items.archive = '0'
```

НО! Сортировались при выводе по: `shop_items_sort as sort ON shop_items.id = sort.item_id and (sort.division_id = shop_items.division_id or shop_items.divisions like CONCAT('%;', sort.division_id, ';%')) , order by sort.sort`

То есть shop_items_sort никак не должен влиять на результат выдачи, а только на порядок. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Вы же это уже спрашивали или почти это. И я вам предложил `ON shop_items.id = sort.item_id and (sort.division_id = shop_items.division_id or shop_items.divisions like CONCAT('%;', sort.division_id, ';%'))` заменить на `ON shop_items.id = sort.item_id  and sort.division_id = 5` вы это пробовали сделать ?

Comment: Сортировка по основному разделу и так работает. Нужно отладить сортировку по дополнительному! т.е. по divisions

Comment: Для дополнительного там стоит sort.division_id=4 или любой другой. этот запрос должен возвращать порядок только для выбираемого раздела, а не для всех разделов в которых находится товар одновременно, как написано у вас сейчас

Comment: И кстати, можете свой запрос выполнить просто как `select *` и вы сразу увидите почему записи дублируются, там будет видно какае значения для тех же самых id отображаются другие и я уверен, что там будут ненужные номера отделов из shop_items_sort